# Making classes for 2D & 3D Points and their types

Tags: oop, inheritance

So I am working on an OOP project (in C++ language) which I need to create a class for 2D points & 3D points. It should also include all types of those points such as Cartesian & polar for 2D AND Cartesian, spherical & cylindrical coordinates for 3D. Conversions from one form to the other should also be available.

I am bit confused how to approach this problem. This is what I came up with:-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a88wt4enqnmxdmc/CPoint.png

If there are any better suggestions or methods, please tell me.

PS: Our instructor advised us to use inheritance in this project.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C++. Sorry I forgot to mention it earlier. I have edited OP to clarify that.